# In terraform plan how to repersent list with using -var

Tags: terraform

This is how my config looks like since I do not check in the tfvars file in to source control when I run it as part of CI CD I will need to use `-var` instead of `-var-file`. when doing this how do I represent list when using with `-var`.

config.tfvars contains

```
subnets = ["subnet-0160740dss2324df7e1","subnet-0faa77cc23fs6776"]
prefix =  "tktest2"
count_webapp = 1
```

when using `terraform plan` instead of using the file `-var-file` we specify each of the parameter by using `-var` how do we represent list. When I run this it gives error and not able to recogenize the list.

```
terraform plan -var subnets=["subnet-0160740dss2324df7e1","subnet-0faa77cc23fs6776"] -var count_webapp=1 -var prefix="tktest2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform itself is expecting to see normal Terraform list syntax here, as shown in [some examples in the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#variables-on-the-command-line).

However, because this is on the command line rather than in a file that Terraform will read directly, there is the extra problem of passing these values through your shell to Terraform without the shell also attempting to parse and interpret it.

If you are using a Unix-style shell, such as `bash` or `zsh` e.g. on Linux or macOS then the easiest way to ensure that the shell does not modify the expression is to use `'` quote characters around the value, like this:

```
terraform apply -var='image_id_list=["ami-abc123","ami-def456"]'
```

If you are running Terraform from the Windows command interpreter then you'll need to use a different escaping syntax, due to the different conventions for command line processing on Windows:

```
terraform apply -var=image_id_list=[\"ami-abc123\",\"ami-def456\"]
```

Here the `\` characters before the `"` characters tell the command line parser to use a literal quote character rather than the usual interpretation of removing the quotes and disabling treating spaces as argument separators.

If you are running Terraform from PowerShell on Windows then unfortunately the answer is considerably more complicated because PowerShell is designed to parse the command line itself, evaluate any PowerShell-specific sequences, then reconstruct a new command line string to use to run Terraform, and that second level of construction and re-parsing makes it hard to control exactly which string will be sent to Terraform. For that reason, if you are using PowerShell then I would suggest either *not* using PowerShell (use the normal Windows command interpreter instead) or  writing your value into a separate `.tfvars` file and passing it with `-var-file` so that Terraform can pass the data exactly as you wrote it, without any interpretation by intermediate systems.

Answer (score 0):

TF [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#variables-on-the-command-line) show how to do it. In your case you can use:

```
terraform plan -var='subnets=["subnet-0160740dss2324df7e1","subnet-0faa77cc23fs6776"]' -var='count_webapp=1' -var='prefix="tktest2"'
```